# Puppet: is there a way to catch failure to apply a resource?

Tags: puppet

is there a way in Puppet to catch a failure when resource is applied, for example, when declaration like

```
 file { '/var/tmp/test':
      ensure => file,
      mode   => '0755',
    }
```

fails, invoke something like

```
exec { 'Register some failure':
    command => '/var/tmp/register failure for /var/tmp/test',
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
  exec { 'Notify a failure' :
      command => "/var/tmp/register failure for /var/tmp/test",
      path => "/bin:",
      subscribe => File["/var/tmp/test"],
  }
```

Comment: It won't work - `.../Exec[Notify a failure]: Skipping because of failed dependencies`

Comment: You have to define what you mean by *catch a failure*... Do you want to correct and force the execution of creation of `/var/tmp/test` file if puppet fails to do so ? In that case, you might just want to write an exec !