# Execute resource in Puppet if another resource fails

Tags: puppet

Say if I have a exec resource like so:

```
exec { 'Task1':
    command => '/bin/long-running-task',
    timeout => 3600,
}
```

If this long running task fails or times out, it'd be optimal to get a notification of this failure.

If the task fails (returns non zero), catching this is basically `/bin/long-running-task || <err catching code>`. Catching the timeout is the issue, as the `||` won't execute here.

Registering a subscribe or notify doesn't work in this situation as the subscribed task will fail due to failed dependencies, i.e.:

```
exec { 'Task1 Failure':
    command => 'echo "Failed to do xxx" | mail -s to@tld',
    subscribe => Exec['Task1'],
}
```

will lead to:

```
Exec[Task1 Failure]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

[This SO question asks the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173654/puppet-is-there-a-way-to-catch-failure-to-apply-a-resource), but has no answers.

Comment: Would this be better as a service than a task? You would have more flexibility with that.